# Getting Ready to work remote... Git Branches

Tags: git, github

I am getting ready to do some work remote from my job but I have a git question.  If I go into my project and I do a

```
git pull
```

does this take down all the branches from the server or just the current one?? I think just the current one.. I need all my branches updated..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ git pull --all
```

Will pull all remote branches, if you already have local branches which need updating you might consider using

```
$ git fetch --all
```